# Stick UIButton into an UIImageView's UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an UIImageView with an UIButton that that I want to be able to send as an image with email, but the UIButton in the UIImageView wont be "stickied" with the UIImageView's image when I take the image out from the UIImageView.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "stickied"?

Comment: I mean... I have an UIImageView which I add a UIButton as the UIImageView's subview. When I try to use the UIImageView.image, I dont get the button which I have added as a subview for the UIImageView.

Comment: Oh thanks RIP, I will do that for all my questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add UIButton and UIImageView and get the required screenshot image using the following code.
 You might  need to add the QuartzCore.framework to your project and #import

To get the image with other UI elements.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 480)); // Here provide width and height of UIImageView
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];//Here use required view 
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();//outputImage is your required image
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

To display the image

```
UIImageView * screenShotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:outputImage];
[screenShotView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:screenShotView];
```